# Drax Pre-Hardmode

Tags: terraria-mobile

I’ve been playing Terraria for several years now, but I’ve only recently downloaded it on mobile. So I’m still pre-hardmode, preparing to fight the wall of flesh.

I was exploring the underworld, when I encountered a shadow chest with a Drax inside it. This confused me, as I know that usually you are required to craft it using souls from all three mechanical bosses, as well as hallowed bars. So it struck me as strange to find this so early on in the game.

Is this usual, or is this some form of bug where another item is supposed to be in the chest instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were playing the PC version, you'd be correct, this is highly unusual. However, on mobile, this is intended and expected, as explained on the [official wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Drax).

> - [Mobile][3DS] The Drax can be found in one Shadow Chests in a world. Because of this, the player has a significant mining advantage, as it can mine all pre-Plantera blocks, at which point the Picksaw is needed. It makes killing Mechanical Bosses much easier, as the player will have access to Chlorophyte weapons and armor.